# FacebookClient.GetTaskAsync Parameters

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk, windows-8, windows-runtime

I am working on a Windows 8 metro prototype app that will post a message to a wall.

I installed the SDK, and so far I have

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    try
    {
        Action<object> action = handleTask;

        var fb = new FacebookClient(FACEBOOK_ID, FACEBOK_SECRET);

        var task = fb.GetTaskAsync("4");

        task.ContinueWith(action);
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

private void handleTask(object data)
{
}
```

The handleTask method gets called, but I can't seem to determine what the type is that's being passed. The data in it appears to be Mark Zuckerberg's FB info (???)

Again, all I need to do is post to a wall. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

```
var fb - new FacebookClient();
fb.GetTaskAsync("4")
  .ContinueWith(t=> 
      if(!t.IsFaulted) {
          dynamic result = t.Result;
          var name = result.name;
      }
  );
```

or change `object data` to `Task<object>` in handleTask

[Update]

*Posting* to wall.

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("access_token");
fb.PostTaskAsync("me/feed", new {message = "hi"});
```

Comment: How does this answer my question of how to post a message on a wall?

Comment: Ok, this compiles and runs, but when I log into my Fb page, I don't see the message. What am doing wrong?

Comment: i would recommend you to check out this sample https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-winforms-sample